# Problems with unit testing in rails especially with foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I cant run unit test in rails.  i keep getting this error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: column email is not unique. i have a foreign key for email in my post model but i dont know why i keep getting the above error. My code is as follows for my test class:

```
test "should not save post without title" do
 post = Post.new
 post.text = "hello world"
 assert !post.save
end

test "should not save post without description" do
 post = Post.new
 post.title = "hello"
 assert !post.save
end
```

Comment: That should be caused by your email value `''`, check your DB and you should see that there is already a record with empty email. Remember to check your test DB instead of development one.

Comment: also look at databasecleaner gem to make sure that your db is starting with a clean slate for every test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that rails 4 does not like using test in the format above. It worked when i changes the method headers to something like:

```
  def test should_not_save_post_without_title
  //add testing code
  end
```

and also make sure that all your model fixtures have sample data in them for every single variable that needs to be tested. An example of this is:

in my Post Fixture:

```
 one:
  text: MyString
  title: MyString
```